# 'qTranslate slug with widget' plugin works with posts but not pages

Tags: plugin-qtranslate

I'm using 'qTranslate slug with widget' plugin which is great, however, I'm stuck on one thing.

If I set permalinks as /%post_id%/%postname%/ as recommended by plugin author - this works with my pages perfectly BUT my posts URL would then include post-id/pretty-permalink e.g. www.website.com/123/webpage (I don't want the post-id to appear).

If I set my permalinks to /%postname%/, my posts URL appear perfect BUT my pages return a 404 (the pages exist - it doesn't to be working with qTranslate slug).

(I'm working on wp3.0.5)
I've searched for answers and seems a couple of people are also having same problem. Anyone also experienced this and found a solution?

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: I suggest you contact the plugin author directly. Then report back here with his/her answer.

Answer (score 1):

I built a solution that dont depends on that permalink structure, you can find follow the changes at this [qtranslate slug 0.5 fix](http://en.codatavern.com/qtranslate-slug-with-widget-wordpress-plugin-fix/)